# Overflowing of text in android TextView

Tags: java, android, animation, textview, css

I am experiencing a rather strange bug with TextView on Android. The text can flow over TextView's top border at random times then user interacts with it. It looks like this happens when TextView changes it height with animation (it expands and shrinks on click).

So here how it looks (views borders drawing enabled with android dev tools, and I've marked TextView's borders with red ) http://s7.postimage.org/c1ynrbwjv/so_full.png

I've tried calling *invalidate()* (*postInvalidate()* either), *requestLayout()* and resetting *gravity* of TextView.
I also tried to rewrite expanding and shrinking animation, to use *getLayoutParams().height* to set height, instead of *setMaxHeight()*.
At the end I've put TextView into LinearLayout (setting TextView height to layout_height="wrap_content"), and expanding/shrinking LinearLayout instead of TextView (so TextView's bounds doesn't change directly). But that, as you can guess, didn't help.

TextView layout (BoardPostText extends TextView):

```
<my.package.view.BoardPostText
    android:id="@+id/postText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/postTitle"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/post_image_max_height"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/post_data_text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/post_data_text_size"
    android:textColorLink="@color/post_link_color" />
```

TextView's code https://gist.github.com/d47e8eafb1bcff7c8db1

Comment: Full layout here [link](https://gist.github.com/9dc5246f8f753144e77a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that such behaviour occured then MotionEvent happened over hyperlink. Because I only need spans to be clickable, I made such workaround:

```
public static class JustClickableMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {

    public static MovementMethod getInstance() {
        return new JustClickableMethod();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        if( action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {

            return true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }

}
```

After setting this movement method to TextView clickable spans still get onClick() event, but bug with text flowing disappears.

I think this is because LinkMovementMethod is "A movement method that traverses links in the text buffer and **scrolls if necessary**. Supports clicking on links with DPad Center or Enter. "